# how to check old $scope before navigating away?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm trying to prevent navigation from a page when the data is not saved yet. So I added

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    console.log('location change. scope.id ' + $scope.$id);
    // here comes the interesting code
});
```

I've read other answers suggesting $stateChangeStart, but that got me nowhere. I tried the same with $stateChangeStart and $routeChangeStart, but none of those events ever occured when I click a link or use my browser's back or forward button.

But my problem with the above implementation: it's already in the new controller and the new scope AFTER the navigation. When I debug it, I notice that the $scope.$id is the id of the scope I'm navigating to and not the $scope.$id I'm navigating away from. But I need to run checks in my old controller and actually stay there in certain cases.

It seems the event is thrown AFTER the new controller is instantiated and therefore the event is caught in the new controller.

Do I need to react on a different event, one that is fire BEFORE the new controller is instantiated? Anyone know which event that is? Or something completely different?

So I added some code to also listen to the $destroy event:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(event) {
    console.log('destroy ' + $scope.$id);
});
```

and this code still runs in the old controller with the old $scope. But I doubt I can use this event hook to check the current state, eventually open a modal and depending on the user interaction continue with the navigation.

Can somebody help here?

AngularJS v1.4.7
angular-ui-router v1.0.23

EDIT: It feels like some global configuration might be off that the $locationChangeStart event is only fired after the new controller is intialized and not before. Anyone have an idea what this might be?

Answer (score 0):

Add event.preventDefault() inside $locationChangeStart. That will keep the location from changing and let you handle some cleanup issues.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current){
    event.preventDefault();         
    // do stuff   
});
```

Comment: preventing default behaviour wasn't my issue. I just answered the question, since I found the solution. The $locationChangeStart event is the wrong event to react on for this task.

Comment: Missed you were using ui-router

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

The $locationChangeStart event is the wrong event to react on. Apparently the "locationChange" is something that happens very, very late in the transition from one state to another. Actually it only gets fired AFTER the new controller is instantiated. So if the controller code reacts on the event, then it is already the new controller.

Therefore: Don't capture the $locationChangeStart event in $scope, but only in $rootScope. Not sure if there is anything useful to do with it in that spot, but at least you will have working code.

The solution is of course (as stated in other answers) the $stateChangeStart event. It is fired when the state starts to change and I can react on that. The event was never thrown in my application was because I hadn't included stateEvents.js and the dependency on ui.router.state.events. Now that this is in place, the event is fired, I can react on it and solve my problem.